# Started or Bound Services?

Tags: android

Which is really for a music player? What's the difference on their behavior? Please let me understand! I'm really confused on what to use. I tried making a music player with a bind service but the problem is every time I exit my application and enter it again, it seems like a new `serviceConnection` is started. I'm expecting that every time I go back to my app, it would still recognize that the music is already fired up. For an instance I have play and pause functions. When i play the music, exit the app, and return, I would be expecting that I could stop the player. But instead, it will play another music. So now I'm confused, should i really use bind? or started service?

```
public class MyService extends Service{

public IBinder myBinder = new MyPlaylistBinder();
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return myBinder;
}
public class MyPlaylistBinder extends Binder{
    MyService getService(){
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
```

The code above is my MyService.java

```
public ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyPlaylistBinder binder = (MyPlaylistBinder) service;
        myService = binder.getService();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service is connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service is disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

};
```

And this one is a portion of my MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnPrevious = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    btnBackward = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
    btnPlay = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnForward = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
    btnNext = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

    ComponentName myService = startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    bindService(intent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    cursor = resolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

Above is a portion of the MainActivity's onCreate()
As you can see I'm not using an AIDL because I haven't tried that and I'm afraid I might make it worse. Please bear with me, I'm just a beginner in android :(

Comment: please illustrate this post with your current code. Without that it's difficult to help.

Comment: I got a problem, I can't post images because my reputation is too low :(

Comment: There is no need for images, just the relevant portion of code

Comment: I edited my post already :)

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html):

> **Started**
>
> A service is "started" when an application component (such as
> an activity) starts it by calling startService(). **Once started, a
> service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component
> that started it is destroyed.** Usually, a started service performs a
> single operation and does not return a result to the caller. For
> example, it might download or upload a file over the network. When the
> operation is done, the service should stop itself.
>
> **Bound**
>
> A service is
> "bound" when an application component binds to it by calling
> bindService(). A bound service offers a client-server interface that
> allows components to interact with the service, send requests, get
> results, and even do so across processes with interprocess
> communication (IPC). A bound service runs only as long as another
> application component is bound to it. **Multiple components can bind to
> the service at once, but when all of them unbind, the service is
> destroyed.**

Based on that, you probably want to start a service since you intend it to keep running after the components that started it are no longer there. As a convenience to the user, you should consider having an ongoing notification as long as the service is running, and include music controls that lets the user directly pause, resume, or completely stop playback (that last one could invoke stopService, at which point you cancel the notification).

Comment: So you're saying that I should use "started" service instead of "bound". Can you please give me an existing application/s that  uses bound services?

Comment: Maybe you can find a tutorial or sample application with a quick Google search. Except for apps I've written, I don't know what developers do inside their apps. But based on your original question, it certainly sounds like you should use a started service.

Comment: I'm thinking of that too. But I want to know in what scenario do components bind to a service?

Comment: There are any number of possibilities. Binding to a service lets you call any public methods of that service. The binding is simply the system's way of managing the lifecycle of that service. What you actually do with it is entirely up to you.